# How to compile old app in Xcode 4.2 to escape GCC error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I've downloaded new Xcode 4.2 and I'm unable to compile the old projects since I'm getting GCC error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the new Xcode tries to update your projects to use their new LLVM compiler. Go to your project settings and check if your compiler is LLVM or GCC (GCC was the old one).

Project -> Build Settings -> Build Options - Compiler for C/C++/Objective C:

Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 (this is the new one)

LLVM GCC 4.2 (that's the old one)